# How to store graph in files

Tags: c++, graph, storing-data

I want to store the following information in a file.
My program is consisted of set of string that are connected forming a graph.
I call each single string "Tag".

let's say we have 3 main tags `$Mohammed` , `$car` , `$color`

Each of the main tags contains sub  tags and each sub tag has a value or another sub tag or set of sub tags.

```
$Mohammad:
    $Age: "18"
    $color: $red
    $kind_of: $human
    $car:
        $type: $toyota
        $color: $blue
        $doors:
            $number: "3"
$car:
    $made_of: $metal
    $used_for: $transporting
    $types: {$mercedes,$toyota,$nissan}
    $best_color: $red

$color:
    $usedto: $coloring_things
    $example: {$red,$green,$blue,...}
```

But this in not the only thing, there is a connection between the tags of the same name, so that `$Mohammed->$car->$color` must be connected with the main tag `$color`. and `$Mohammed->$color:$red` , `$car->$best_color:$red` , `$color->$best_color: $red` and the main tag $red must all be connected to each other.

The tags connected means be stored in a way that I can call the connected tags at once. just like the computer memory. when it calls something from the memory, it calls the information before and after the requested information.

When I looked to my situation in the first time, I thought that XML would solve it, but then I realized that XML can't represent graph.

I don't want to use databases for this. I want to keep database as my last weapon.

Any idea or suggestion about how can I store,connect and recall the informations from my program?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a loot at boost's [`property_tree`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/property_tree.html)

It contains a nice c++ way to represent your graph, and let's you very easily decide what kind of file-representation you want. Be that `xml`, `json`, `info`.

Also, I don't see why your graph can't be represented by `xml`, as it supports named nodes.

Although `property_tree` also supports the `ini` format, that actually can't represent your >2 level deep tree.

Comment: I'm already using a struct like `property_tree` in my code, but the problem is in storing the relations and tags in the same file so that I can recall all connected tags at once.

Comment: If you can't replace your struct with `property_tree`, then writing a simple loader/writer to and from, gives you all you need to write/load to/from file. `write_json(yourType.toPropertyTree())`, and `yourType(read_json(...))`

Answer (score 2):

You actually could use XML, but I would recommend JSON or Yaml.

Your example format is already very close to Yaml.

Comment: I took a look on Yaml website. It looks more like a tree than a graph,I coudn't find any way to present the connections between tags.

Comment: Actually, Yaml can handle graphs. See http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2763754